# problem to make heritable a class with lazy and static method

Tags: inheritance, .net-core

In a wcf net 6.0 service that I've been working on for a few days, NLog is used. There are several Class Libraries and in each of them there is always the same code, a simple copy-paste was done by changing only the name of the class.

This is the class present several times with different names SomeClass1LoggerService, SomeClass2LoggerService, SomeClass3LoggerService, SomeClass4LoggerService..... only class name a log file name are changing.

```
public class SomeClassLoggerService
{
    public static LogFactory Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
    private static Lazy<LogFactory> _instance = new Lazy<LogFactory>(BuildLogFactory);

    private static LogFactory BuildLogFactory()
    {
        string basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string configFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, "SomeClass.nlog");

        LogFactory logFactory = new LogFactory();
        logFactory.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(configFilePath, logFactory);
        return logFactory;
    }
}
```

this the code to get the log instance:

```
static NLog.ILogger _Logger = SomeClassxLoggerService.Instance.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

i tried to create a derived class like this:

```
public class SomeDerivedClassLoggerService:SomeClassLoggerService
{
}
```

but the problem is Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() returns always the name and path of the base class, i need to create the log with derived class name and path. it seems to me there is no way to pass to
SomeClassLoggerService the instance of derived class so i can create the log in the right place e with derived class name. in this sample the log file for SomeDerivedClassLoggerService should be named SomeDerivedClass.nlog e saved in the same path of SomeDerivedClass.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use generics and pass the derived types as generic argument to the base class ? If this is acceptable you can write something like :

```cs
public abstract class SomeClassLoggerService<T> where T : SomeClassLoggerService<T>
{
    public static LogFactory Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
    private static Lazy<LogFactory> _instance = new Lazy<LogFactory>(BuildLogFactory);

    private static LogFactory BuildLogFactory()
    {
        string basePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(T).Assembly.Location);
        string configFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, $"{typeof(T).Name}.nlog");

        LogFactory logFactory = new LogFactory();
        logFactory.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(configFilePath, logFactory);
        return logFactory;
    }
}

public class SomeDerivedClassLoggerService : SomeClassLoggerService<SomeDerivedClassLoggerService>
{
}
```

Comment: it seems to work, just need to do some thorough testing. in your code typeof(T).Name returns the name of the derived class, i need the dll name so changed to $"{typeof(T).Assembly.GetName().Name}.nlog".